# Объединить 2 хендлера pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

```
@bot.message_handler()
def send_docs(message):
if message.text in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','v']:
    file_source=open(f"D:\Proyekt\domstroy_{message.text}.csv")
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file_source) 

elif:
    @bot.message_handler()
    def send_query(message):
        db=sqlite3.connect("ostatki.db",check_same_thread=False)
        cur=db.cursor()
        cur.execute("DROP table IF EXISTS tovarniye_ostatki")
        cur.execute("CREATE virtual table IF NOT EXISTS tovarniye_ostatki USING FTS5 
        (nazvaniye_tovara,ostatki_tovara)")
        with open ("domstroy.csv",'r', encoding="utf8",) as file:
            for row in file:   
                cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tovarniye_ostatki VALUES 
        (?,?)",row.split(";"),)
            db.commit()
        result_query = cur.execute("SELECT ostatki_tovara, nazvaniye_tovara  FROM  
                                   tovarniye_ostatki 
                                   WHERE tovar_nomi MATCH (?)",(message.text,))
        result = result_query.fetchall()
        for i in result:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, (f"{i[1]} == {i[0]}"))
        db.close()
```

Мне надо объединить эти 2 хендлера.
1-Хендлер должен отправить файл, если юзер отправить цифры от 1 до 10 и букву v.
2-Хендлер должен сработать, если юзер отправит например, запрос "travertin" то есть название товара из БД.
Сейчас работает только 1-хендлер.
Подскажите, пожалуйста где ошибка.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала скажу, что второй хендлер не факт, что будет работать. Но как мысль о том как примерно можно реализовать вам поможет.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_docs(message):
    l = []
    with open('test.csv', encoding='utf8') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for i in reader:
            a = i[0]
            a = a.split(';')[0]
            l.append(a)

    if message.text in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','v']:
        file_source=open(f"D:\Proyekt\domstroy_{message.text}.csv")
        bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file_source)

    elif message.text in l:
        db=sqlite3.connect("ostatki.db",check_same_thread=False)
        cur=db.cursor()
        cur.execute("DROP table IF EXISTS tovarniye_ostatki")
        cur.execute("CREATE virtual table IF NOT EXISTS tovarniye_ostatki USING FTS5
        (nazvaniye_tovara,ostatki_tovara)")
        with open ("domstroy.csv",'r', encoding="utf8",) as file:
            for row in file:
                cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tovarniye_ostatki VALUES
        (?,?)",row.split(";"),)
            db.commit()
        result_query = cur.execute("SELECT ostatki_tovara, nazvaniye_tovara  FROM
                                   tovarniye_ostatki
                                   WHERE tovar_nomi MATCH (?)",(message.text,))
        result = result_query.fetchall()
        for i in result:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, (f"{i[1]} == {i[0]}"))
        db.close()
```

Вам стоит в хендлере открыть БД, и считать вам нужные названия, а потом циклом вставить в список. И уже данный список проверять на схожесть с `message.text`

Так же хочу, чтобы вы обратили внимание на ваш код. Вы вставили хендлер в условие, что делать нельзя, просто работать не будет. Можно лишь попробовать вызвать функцию, что стоит под хендлером, но лично я так не делал, так что не могу сказать точно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
но здесь "elif message.text in ['названия, на которые должен отвзываться бот'] "я заранее не знаю что запросить юзер.

Comment: @Marina У вас же есть БД с названиями? Если да, то прежде чем будет выбор if-elif вы должны вытащить все названия из БД и поместить в список, а дальше уже проверять есть ли нужное название в этом списке. Если да, то выполняется elif, если же это цифра или v, то  if. Надеюсь вы поняли меня, если нет, то пример реализую в коде как можно это сделать

Comment: Первый вариант точно не будет работать

Comment: @oleksandrigo Я догадывался, но не был уверен точно

Comment: файл с 'csv' файла импортируется в БД, тогда могу сразу взять данные до загрузки в БД.

Comment: @Otets Valerian, почему то н получается.

Comment: @Marina Вы пробовали выводить список для проверки, что он правильно формируется? Если да, то добавьте полученный код в Ваш вопрос, чтобы посмотреть в чем именно дело. Если нет, то выведите. В случае, если все правильно вывелось, то названия должны выйти в списке. В ином случае добивайтесь, чтобы выводился список

Comment: даже не знаю с чего начать

Comment: import csv
l=[]
with open('domstroy.csv', encoding='utf8') as file:
    reader=csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')
    for i in reader:
        l.append(i)
только это пришла в голову

Comment: @Marina Я исправил код. Должно работать. Для проверки после цикла ```for i in reader:``` выведите полученный список. Должен выводиться полностью первый столбец

Comment: Сработала, спасибо большое.